# How to change the target span onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want a line-through to appear on the span content onClick in React. Have tried creating a state and associating it to the li. But onclick, it affects all the li tags. I want it to only change the style of the particular li tag. I am new to react and trying to learn slowly.

```
import React from 'react';

class Todos extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };

  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){
    const click = this.state.clicked;
    console.log(click)
    if(click){
      this.setState({
        clicked: false
      })
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        clicked: true
      })
    }
    console.log(this.state.clicked);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="bg-warning p-4 list-group"> 
        {this.props.todos.length ? (
          this.props.todos.map(todo => {
            return (
              <li className="list-group-item" key={todo.id}>
                <span className="pr-2">{todo.content}</span>
                <button onClick={()=>{this.props.deleteTodo(todo.id)}}>Delete</button>
              </li>
            )
          })
        ) : (
          <p className="center">You have no todo's left, yay!</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }

}

export default Todos;
```

Comment: When you click `Delete` button the todo item will get delete from the list, correct?

Comment: yes it removes the todo item

Comment: In that case, when use click on todo item (span) you want it to be `line-through` and on click of delete you want it to be deleted, correct?

Comment: yes, i have tried with the onclick event but what happens when i click on the span all the todo items have line-through

Comment: Hi parul, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eramit2010 answer makes sense, but I am extending it to fit the requirement that, when clicked on todo item (i.e. span) show `line-through` and when clicked on delete button simply delete the todo item.

You need to maintain clicked todo's in a state array,

```
state ={
  clickedTodo: []
}
```

You should have separate click event on your span where you want to show `line-through`,

```
<span 
   className="pr-2" 
   style={{textDecoration: this.state.clickedTodo.includes(index) ? 'line-through' : 'none', paddingRight: '20px', cursor:'pointer'}} 
   onClick={() => this.lineThrought(todo.id)}
>
   {todo.content}
</span>
```

Here, I have applied `CSS` to make span `line-through` when it gets clicked.

Your `lineThrought` method should be,

```
lineThrought = (id) => {
  if(this.state.clickedTodo.includes(id)){
    //To remove line-through
    this.setState({clickedTodo: this.state.clickedTodo.filter(item => item !== id)})
  }else{
    //To add line-through
    this.setState({clickedTodo: [...this.state.clickedTodo, id]})
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-shr8bd)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but only one small issue i have is that if a todo item is has a line-through and i add a new todo, automatically the new todo has a line-through

Comment: Oh, I also realize that, instead of `index` we need to store the `todo.id` in array so that when new item get's added it should not get line-through. I have also updated Demo, check it now.

Answer (score 1):

you can store deleted ids in local state and then if that perticular id is present in state, you can use custom class for that.

```
consturctor() {
   this.state = {
       deleted: []
   };
}
render() {
    return (
      <ul className="bg-warning p-4 list-group"> 
        {this.props.todos.length ? (
          this.props.todos.map(todo => {
            return (
              <li className=`list-group-item ${this.state.deleted.includes(todo.id) ? "list-group-item-deleted" : ""}` key={todo.id}>
                <span className="pr-2">{todo.content}</span>
                <button onClick={()=> {
                    this.props.deleteTodo(todo.id);
                    this.setState(prevState => { deleted: [...prevState.deleted, todo.id]);
                }>Delete</button>
              </li>
            )
          })
        ) : (
          <p className="center">You have no todo's left, yay!</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

in your css file:

```
.list-group-item-deleted {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

If you are already storing deleted ids in redux or somewhere else you can use same.

Comment: my delete function is in the parent component and the function is as  ** deleteTodo = (id) => {
    const todos = this.state.todos.filter((todo) => {
      return todo.id !== id;
    })
    //filter makes a copy of the array, if the return is false, then the todo associated with the id is deleted
    this.setState({
      todos
    })
    //in the above function instead of todos: todos, we are directly only mentioning todos which means the same
  }**

Answer (score 0):

When someone click in li then it will perform deleteTodo, you said you want it to only change the style of the particular li tag, you can easily perform that using below code inside of you componentdidmount() function

`$(document).on('click', 'your class name' , function() 
 { $(this).css('color','red');
 });`

Otherwise, you have to use dynamic state, based on unique id, when someone click event then use that id as a state and change those li color.

Comment: then you have to use dynamic state, based on unique id, when someone click event then use that id as a state and change those li color